# I'd like to get a question reopened - what's the difference between a shopping question, and not

Tags: support, status-completed

[How to buy a computer that supports multiple monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/485019/how-to-buy-a-computer-that-supports-multiple-monitors/) I'd like to get this question reopened, since its not actually a shopping recommendation.

The intent behind shopping recommendations is to avoid answers that go stale. This is the *other* sort of shopping question - A good answer is valid, indefinately. Its a practical problem (How do I know the computer I'm going to buy supports more than one monitor?) and supports a *class* of answers, rather than 'get a X'.

I SERIOUSLY recommend that we reopen this, and that folk *please* understand the intention behind closing shopping questions rather than just closing them for having the word 'buy' in them.

Comment: I agree. These type of shopping questions are rare... I mean, the usable questions are rare

Comment: *folk please understand the intention behind closing shopping questions rather than just closing them for having the word 'buy' in them* – same for "best", IMO